# Commandbinding in DataGridTemplateColumn not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

In my xaml-code i have the following DataGridTemplateColumn

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Button x:Name="categoryButton" Style="{StaticResource Flat}"
                  Tag="{Binding Category}"
                  Command="{Binding SelectCategoryCommand,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=categoryButton,
                                               Path=Tag}">
              <Image Source="{Binding Category, Converter={StaticResource 
                                                        categoryConverter}}"/>
          </Button>
       </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The SelectCategoryCommand-Property in the ViewModel is:

```
        private ICommand selectCategoryCommand;
        public ICommand SelectCategoryCommand
        {
            get { return this.selectCategoryCommand; }
            set
            {
                this.selectCategoryCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectCategoryCommand");
            }
        }
```

And in the constructor of the ViewModel I have:

```
...
this.SelectCategoryCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectCategory);
...
```

And the SelectCategory-Method is just

```
private void SelectCategory(object parameter)
{
   MessageBox.Show("dummy");
}
```

The connection between the view and the viewmodel works. I have some other properties where the binding works fine.

Why is the SelectCategory-Method is not invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this code `Command="{Binding SelectCategoryCommand`, command will be searching in row DataContext (in model class). So if your command is in main view model you should use `RelativeSource` binding.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="categoryButton" Style="{StaticResource Flat}" Tag="{Binding Category}"
                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectCategoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=categoryButton, Path=Tag}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Category, Converter={StaticResource categoryConverter}}"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The WPF DataGrid is a type of [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx). Now, with an `ItemsControl`, each individual control generated in the view (the ones for individual items) have their `DataContext` set to that item in the collection. For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}" />

public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { ... }
```

In this situation, the `DataGridRow`'s DataContext would be set to an instance of a `Foo`. My guess is that your command is in the same ViewModel that the collection sits at, and not at the level of the individual items. You'll either have to use the `RelativeSource` to reference back to the `DataGrid` itself so you can access the `DataContext` on that level, or items in your collection will need to be ViewModels of their own that contain the command at their level.